# How to fill the branch name in Jenkins dynamically

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

Is there an option to pass the branch from shell script or may be a aws parameter store in to Jenkins?

[image]

How do I add value in "Branches to build" field dynamically?

We are storing the branch names in AWS ssm parameter store and fetching it in Jenkins script while build phase. Searched every where about this but couldn't get any leads on it

Answer (score 1):

## Dynamic Branches

You can add the branch dynamically by adding `${BRANCH_NAME}` ( where BRANCH_NAME is the name of the parameter that contains your branch name )

[image: branch name]

> Make sure that **lightweight checkout** is **not** selected.  If this option is selected I may not allow you to use a parameter in the *Branches to build* field

With that said, I don't know what you mean by "build phase".  This configuration is used to clone the repository that contains your Jenkinsfile.  This will execute before your Jenkinsfile is pulled down ( so before any step or stage is executed ).

If you need to execute some code first ( for example, pulling a value from AWS SSM ) you will need to clone again in your Jenkinsfile `git branch: '${BRANCH_BAME}', url: ''`

Comment: From where does the value of parameter `${BRANCH_NAME}` come from? I understand when you said `"you need to clone again in Jenkinsfile"` ?

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `Pipeline script` instead of `Pipeline script from SCM`, and then you can write a pipeline script to load the actual jenkins file you want to run after code checkout. For example,

```
String branch = env.GIT_BRANCH  // suppose you read your branch from env that provided by parameters or injected by gitlab trigger, etc
node {
  git(branch, ...)  // checkout
  load Jenkinsfile  // laod the actually Jenkinsfile you want to run
}
```